# Disabling trace.axd at the machine level in ASP.NET 2.0 in Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net, trace

On Windows Server 2003 64-bit set to run as 32, I want to change the global web.config at C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config

To disable tracing.

I see the add..path here:

I think I need to remove that; will doing this help?
()

Will I need to reboot after changing the web.config or just restart the server? I'm assuming that change will propogate to other web.config files and within those if I want to enable/disable tracing I'll make the indicated changes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Also, editing machine.config will recycle all AppDomains so you don't have to do a manual reboot.

To disable trace, you can do this:

```
<trace
    enabled="false"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Where in machine.config does it go?

Comment: Anywhere inside `<system.web></system.web>`